# How to use my created SQLite DB in SQLite Manager apps in my Android program

Tags: android, sqlite, navicat, sql-manager

As I'm working with many tables in my Android application, I decide to create database(DB) in SQLite managers (such as firefox plugin or navicat for sqlite). I finished creating them and export the .sql file ! but I don't know how to use this file! 
Of course I found some post about this  to put DB (on a rooted phone) in ...data/data/{your package name}/ ..etc but I don't understand what to do after this step!! (I know the code for introducing the db to the android app only!!)

- Can anyone tell me step by step How to use my created db with these methods in my Application??-
- Is it good way to use these SQLite managers or despite of being complicated to create multi tables in android with codes, you prefer it???
- What is the main differense between sqlite 2 and 3? Are they supported by different Android version or only updates for Sqlite?

Edit: After copying the dB into assest folder and using the code for copying it:

```
03-16 11:32:20.370: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(3999): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = cannot open file at line 27712 of [8609a15dfa], db=/data/data/com.androidhive.xmlparsing/databases/surveydb.sqlite
03-16 11:32:20.370: I/SqliteDatabaseCpp(3999): sqlite returned: error code = 14, msg = os_unix.c: open() at line 27712 - "" errno=2 path=/data/data/com.androidhive.xmlparsing/databases/surveydb.sqlite, db=/data/data/com.androidhive.xmlparsing/databases/surveydb.sqlite
03-16 11:32:20.370: E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(3999): sqlite3_open_v2("/data/data/com.androidhive.xmlparsing/databases/surveydb.sqlite", &handle, 1, NULL) failed
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999): Failed to open the database. closing it.
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:983)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:932)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at database.AssetDatabaseHelper.checkExist(AssetDatabaseHelper.java:55)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at database.AssetDatabaseHelper.importIfNotExist(AssetDatabaseHelper.java:81)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:78)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-16 11:32:20.380: E/SQLiteDatabase(3999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:983)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:956)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:932)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at database.AssetDatabaseHelper.checkExist(AssetDatabaseHelper.java:55)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at database.AssetDatabaseHelper.importIfNotExist(AssetDatabaseHelper.java:81)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity.onCreate(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.java:78)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1050)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1782)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1834)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$500(ActivityThread.java:122)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1027)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4126)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:844)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
03-16 11:32:20.380: W/System.err(3999):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I used this code:

```
public class AssetDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

 private String dbName;
    private String db_path;
    private Context context;

    /**
     * A helpe r class to import db files.
     * 
     * @param context
     *  base/app context
     * @param dbName
     *            The name of the db in asset folder .
     */
    public AssetDatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbName) {
        super(context, dbName, null, 1);
        this.dbName = dbName;
        this.context = context;
        db_path = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    public boolean checkExist() {

        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = db_path + dbName;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();


        } catch (Exception ep) {
            ep.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (checkDB != null) {

            checkDB.close();

        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void importIfNotExist() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkExist();

        if (dbExist) {
            // do nothing - database already exist
        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {

                copyDatabase();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                throw new Error("Error copying database");

            }
        }

    }
    /**
     * Creates copies the database from asset to the new database location.
     * */
    private void copyDatabase() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(dbName);

        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(db_path + dbName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int length;
        while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        is.close();
        this.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }


}
```

UpdATE 2: db sCRIPTS:

```
CREATE TABLE "**" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "**" TEXT, "****" INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "***" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "***" INTEGER UNIQUE , "***" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE "**" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "***" INTEGER UNIQUE , "**" INTEGER, "**" INTEGER, "**" TEXT, "impGender" TEXT, "**" TEXT, "***" INTEGER, "***" DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
CREATE TABLE "**" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "**" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE "**" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "***" INTEGER UNIQUE , "***" TEXT, "srQType" INTEGER, "***" INTEGER, "**" BOOL, "**" FLOAT, "**" FLOAT, "**" INTEGER, "**"  UNIQUE );
CREATE TABLE "*" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "**" INTEGER NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "***" INTEGER, "**" INTEGER, "**" INTEGER, "**" INTEGER, "**" TEXT, "**" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE "**" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "***" TEXT);
CREATE TABLE "**" ("_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "**" TEXT, "srDesc" TEXT, "***" INTEGER, "**" DATETIME, "**" DATETIME, "****" INTEGER, "srCode" INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US');
```

And at the end:

```
new AssetDatabaseHelper(this , "surveydb.sqlite").importIfNotExist();
```

what is the problem?

Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Sqlite 3 is supported in Android.
- You DO NOT need a rooted phone to use a imported database

Steps to use imported database:

1. Dump your database in /assets folder.
2. Add the code from [git hub here](https://github.com/wtsang02/DbAssetHelper)
3. Import your database by executing the code below.

   ```
       AssetDatabaseHelper dbHelper = new AssetDatabaseHelper(
           getBaseContext(), YOUR_DATABASE_NAME);
   try {
       dbHelper.importIfNotExist();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

Comment: 1 more Question: my DB (was created with those softwares) are in ".sql" format, not .sqlite !!! Is it OK?

Comment: I create mine with firefox's sqlite manager as well. You DO NOT click `export`. A newly created data base IS a file with .sqlite extension. All you need is that file. and follow the steps.

Comment: Excuse me , but it doesn't work for me!!! I edit the question with the  logcat error!

Comment: You have to catch the exception the first time it creates. I updated code.

Comment: Are you sure your not trying to open it before executing this code? This code should be the very first thing you do with your database.

Comment: Actually I didn't write any code to open it! I only want to create DB in the app, if it is successful , I will try to open it!

Comment: 1) did you make sure you have a table called android_metadata?with value android_metadata='en_US'? 2)every table has primary key of "_id" ? [Source Tutorial](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/)

Comment: yes, of course, see the updated Q. for DB script!! May be I should recreate db? I have no idea, every thing is the same as what the tutorial said!!! :(

Comment: I found a problem similar to yours. This is the [solution](http://www.itsalif.info/content/check-if-database-exist-android-sqlite3openv2-failed)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It was my fault that I thought the tutorial is 100% correct!! I should have googled it by myself! Any way, that's helped me, thanks!